# Slim framework dynamic routes

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, slim

I am working with Slim Framework. I would like to make dynamic routes so that my index.php files is not full of static routes.

Instead of having this that works :

```
$app->get('/mypage', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('mypage.php', compact('app'));
})->name('mypage');
```

I would like to have something like this (that does not work) :

```
$app->get('/:name', function($name) use ($app) {
    $app->render('template.php', compact('app', 'name'));
})->name(:name);
```

thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1):

`->name(:name)` assigns a name to the route. The name has to be a string. But you don't need this to create a dynamic route, you can just write

```
$app->get('/:name', function($name) use ($app) {
    $app->render('template.php', compact('app', 'name'));
})
```

More on route names:

- To create a named route: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Names
- To use a named route: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Helpers
  (the URL For paragraph)

Update: The above is an answer for the **V2** version of the Slim framework. More on naming routes in Slim V3 here: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-names

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I would like to use the name of a dynamic route in order to use urlFor() on my links.

Comment: is there any way to create dynamic route patterns ? from array of from JSON keys ?